# How to get clickable list item with php switch to work

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I've built a very basic switch for my website, and it works fine.
What I have trouble with is a clickable list items. The idea behind is when I click on any of the list items - switch displays the appropriate greetinig (whether I click on Night or Afternoon). For some reason it only works for "test.php?timeNow=Night"
Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
if(isset($_GET['timeNow'])) {
    $timeNow = $_GET['timeNow'];
} else {
    $timeNow = date('H:i a');
}

if ($timeNow < 4) {
    $timeNow = 'Night';
} elseif ($timeNow < 12) {
    $timeNow = 'Morning';
} elseif($timeNow < 18) {
    $timeNow = 'Afternoon';
} else {
    $timeNow = 'Evening';
}

switch($timeNow) {
    case 'Night' : 
        $greeting = 'Good night!';
        break;

    case 'Morning' : 
        $greeting = 'Good morning!';
        break;

    case 'Afternoon' : 
        $greeting = 'Good afternoon!';
        break;

    case 'Evening' : 
        $greeting = 'Good evening!';
        break;

}
?> 
        <blockquote>
            <?php echo $greeting; ?> Welcome to this website!
        </blockquote>
         <p><?php echo $timeNow; ?></p> 

        <ul> 
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Night">Night</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Morning">Morning</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Afternoon">Afternoon</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Evening">Evening</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the if statement where you're comparing **string** with **integer** type value and it's returning **true**

```
$timeNow = 'Night';
if ($timeNow < 4) return true;
else return false;
```

This statement will always return true because `$timeNow < 4` is **true** in this case

Comment: Yes, that is the reason exactly, but the problem was rather in the wrong list href rather than if statement itself :)  Thank you for your contribution!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please add breaks `(and move the if-then-else block to the correct place)`. Please amend your codes to the following and try the effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

if(isset($_GET['timeNow'])) {
    $timeNow = $_GET['timeNow'];
} else {
    $timeNow = date('H:i a');

if ($timeNow < 4) {
    $timeNow = 'Night';
} elseif ($timeNow < 12) {
    $timeNow = 'Morning';
} elseif($timeNow < 18) {
    $timeNow = 'Afternoon';
} else {
    $timeNow = 'Evening';
}

    
    }



switch($timeNow) {
    case 'Night' : 
        $greeting = 'Good night!';
        break;

    case 'Morning' : 
        $greeting = 'Good morning!';
        break;

    case 'Afternoon' : 
        $greeting = 'Good afternoon!';
        break;

    case 'Evening' : 
        $greeting = 'Good evening!';
        break;

}
?> 
        <blockquote>
            <?php echo $greeting; ?> Welcome to this website!
        </blockquote>
         <p><?php echo $timeNow; ?></p> 

        <ul> 
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Night">Night</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Morning">Morning</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Afternoon">Afternoon</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Evening">Evening</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I, actually, had breaks before I posted here. I deleted many lines of the code from the post in hopes to make it shorter haha. But yeah, the clickable list items are still selecting only night, yet switch itself works perfectly fine and accordingly to the if statement

Comment: Lack of breaks would have caused the *last* value to always be applied, not the first one.

Comment: @El_Vanja, yeah, as mentioned above, I only deleted breaks from the post only by accident in order to make the post shorter :) I had breaks in the code originally. My switch works fine, I have trouble with list items, where a person can manually select switch case, which will appear in address line like test.php?timeNow=Morning

Comment: Hi @holycanoly, I have further amended the codes in my answer. Please see whether now a person can manually select switch case now.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I found the issue.
The thing is that the list items below return a string (ie. pagename.php?timeNow = string value)

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Night">Night</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Morning">Morning</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Afternoon">Afternoon</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=Evening">Evening</a></li>
</ul>
```

So instead, to make it work we need to use numeric value (a time of day), so it could be applied to the following if statement, and after - to the switch cases

```
if ($timeNow < 4) {
    $timeNow = 'Night';
} elseif ($timeNow < 12) {
    $timeNow = 'Morning';
} elseif($timeNow < 18) {
    $timeNow = 'Afternoon';
} else {
    $timeNow = 'Evening';
}
```

**What needed to be done is the following:**

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=3">Night</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=11">Morning</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=17">Afternoon</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?timeNow=22">Evening</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically, we're giving an hour that will fall into the needed time slot for night, morning, afternoon, and evening.
Considering the if statement, if timeNow = 3, it falls under the first if case (which is less than 4) which means that timeNow = Night, which will essentially use the Night switch case.

A very silly mistake, yet no one noticed :)

I hope this thread would help someone in the future!